# Send checkbox Array with jquery ft.upload, PhoneGap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cordova, upload

I have some checkboxes in my app, which could be checked (naturally). This checkboxes are named like 'checkboxname[]', and every checkbox has it's own value (4,5,6,7,8, and so on).

Now I would like to get all the values (just from the checked checkboxes!!) into an array, send this array over ft.upload, and split the array with foreach with php. But my php file is always saying that the arguments are invalid for my foreach function.

Heres the javascript.

```
var values = new Array();
$("input[name='checkboxname[]']:checked").each(function(){values.push($(this).val());});
params.checkboxname = values;
```

Heres the php code.

```
$rubriks = $_POST['checkboxname'];
foreach($rubriks as $ausgabe){ 
 echo $ausgabe; }
```

I don't know whats wrong. I tested with var_dump whats actually send from the javascript, an theres no checkbox-array so I think there is the problem?!

Comment: What do you see when you alert the `values` array? `alert(values);`

Comment: is there any js errors ?

Comment: When I alert the values I get the right values from the checked checkboxes.

Comment: ok i've got it. the problem (i think) was that ft.upload sends an array, and the checkbox.values were also an array, and array in array doesn't work. so i put the checkbox.values into a string, divided by an "," and send this over ft.upload to the php file, where i exploded the string by "," and put that into an array. thanks for the answers!